# call a function when KDCircularProgress animation is done

Tags: ios, swift, kdcircularprogress

Have anyone used [KDCircularProgress](https://github.com/kaandedeoglu/KDCircularProgress)? If yes, how can I do something when the animation is done?

```
circularProgressView.animateToAngle(360, duration: 5, completion:nil)
```

Any idea how to call a function when the animation is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the completion:

```
circularProgressView.animateToAngle(360, duration: 5) { completed in
    if completed {
        // Animation was completed
    } else {
        // Animation was interrupted
    } 
}
```

Comment: @ dzk Thanks a lot, I guess I don't fully understand closures. I was trying to do something like...`circularProgressView.animateToAngle(1, duration: 0.1, completion: ({finished in someFunction()}))` can you explain why were you able to add a closure and omitting the `duration:` parameter and actually adding the closure body after closing the parenthesis of the `animateToAngle` method? Thanks a lot

Comment: The completion in this specific function looks like this: `((Bool) -> Void)?`. This is a block that takes a boolean value and returns void, so the `closure: _` can be substituted for a completion block which is what you can see in my answer.

Comment: Got it, basically like this...`circularProgressView.animateToAngle(360, duration: 0.5, completion:{
            (finished: Bool) in
            if finished{
                print("Done")
            }
        })` Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Correct, but you don't need to explicitly define `finished` as a `Bool`, as it's already declared as a `Bool` in the function.